# HTML5 drag and drop between windows

Tags: windows, image, html, drag-and-drop, desktop

is there anyway  with the HTML5 Drag & Drop functionality or/and the File API to drag an jpg image from one window to another?

The idea is that I could drag and image from Facebook to a different browser's window with a custom HTML that would get that image.

Or, at least, a way to drag from the Desktop to a browser?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just added more info to my answer after doing some testing

Answer (score 20):

Not sure about between windows, but certainly from the desktop:

http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Photos

Actually, check out the full [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/) site for ideas.

---

EDIT:

I just opened [this demo](http://decafbad.com/2009/07/drag-and-drop/api-demos.html#delegated) in two separate browser windows, and I can drag from one window to the other. I was also able to drag a thumbnail from Facebook and drop it into a drop zone.

However, the Facebook image was dropped as "unknown". So it looks like you can drop from one site to another, but I'm not sure what exactly really gets dropped. If you are dragging from Facebook or such, Facebook may need to have the images or elements have the `draggable` property set or something else that your application can read.

Bottom line is that you should be able to make it work between applications that you have control over. But if you are trying to integrate it with external apps, you will need to do some experimentation to find out what exactly gets passed during the drag/drop. I haven't done this work myself, but it shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old one, but since I recently tussled with it and there is more to this than you might think, I put an answer in. As an introduction to learn about the native methods refer to [this site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/).

That will get you so far. When it comes to dragging between windows, things get smelly. The problem is that once again, there isn't much consistency between browsers. Open up a bunch of different browsers and then [open this excellent example](http://html5demos.com/drag-anything). Select the first `getData('Text')` radio button and test dragging and dropping images. The first thing that you will notice is that in some instances getData('Text') contains a url, but not the image url. So, now choose `getData(e.dataTransfer.types[0]) based on detected content type` radio button. You will notice depending on which browser you choose that some types contain the url to the image appears, but each browser has different types. At the time of writing this some browsers (Internet Explorer) don't have any types that have the image url. This is why if you open up Google images in Internet Explorer and try that funky drag-drop image search, nothing happens - no 'drop here' box appears.

So, the best I have come up with is (make sure you refer to those links above otherwise you won't know what I am going on about): -

1. Check `e.dataTransfer.files`. If there are files then all is well. This is most likely a drop from the local computer. If not, go to step 2.
2. Loop through `getData(e.dataTransfer.types[0])` and pass the url to a regex that checks for a string containing the image url. Something like:

   ```
   RegExp( 'http://(.(?!http://))+?(?:[.]jpg|[.]jpeg|[.]png|[.]gif|[.]tiff|[.]ico)', 'gmi' )
   ```

   If you find a match then all good. Do whatever you want, such as passing to server to retrieve image. If not, go to step 3.
3. Try `getData('Text')`. If you find a match then good. Pass on to server, etc. If not, go to step 4.
4. You are out of luck. Show the user with an unsupported message and ask them to provide the image another way.

Comment: getData('URL') always gives result where getData('Text') does in some browsers

Comment: Very nice summary of how to deal with the problem.I'd like to add that the regular expression should also consider https in addition to http, for example `RegExp( '(http|https)://(.(?!(http|https)://))+?(?:[.]jpg|[.]jpeg|[.]png|[.]gif|[.]tiff|[.]ico)', 'gmi' )`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery you could have a look at this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Drag-and-drop-uploads-from-another-web-page

On the about page:
It works by sending a JSONP request with the URL of the image to Google's servers via the Google App Engine1. The server then converts the image into base64 encoded data URL and sends the image back as a JSON object. This means that the image can be locally included on the website and therefore it can be edited by the canvas tag.

I haven't tried it yet, but will be taking a look at it soon!

Comment: This might work, but it requires [$.getImageData](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/) because of browsers' same origin policies.  $.getImageData uses http://img-to-json.appspot.com to retrieve the image data.  Currently that service is over quota and not accepting requests.  As it was in in [September 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238581/getimagedata-not-working-because-img-to-json-is-down).

Answer (score 3):

*getting the url from the dragged image, 100% ok to firefox and chrome *

```
$('#element').bind('drop', function (e) {
    alert($($.trim($(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')).html())).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: What is this one line?! I tried to simplify it: https://gist.github.com/qgustavor/a07fb552f8117607a56b27d00e7bb20c

Answer (score 1):

I know you can very easily get the URL of the image that was dragged:
myDataTransfer.getData("Text")

but so far I haven't been able to find a way to retrieve the underlying image data without falling foul of cross-domain javascript security... you can't fetch the image using ajax, and you can't use a canvas as an intermediary either.

Unfortunately, it seems that in most cases, the drag itself (that is, the dataTransfer object) doesn't contain the image data.  I say "most cases" because drags from within the same browser don't, but when I dragged from a Firefox window to a Chrome window, it seems to have included some kind of bitmap image, but it's in some unusual format (perhaps a Windows thing).

The only other thing to look at is browser-specific functionality, like "application/x-moz-nativeimage", but I don't see any similar property attached to the dataTransfer object in Chrome.

Comment: If you are only trying to grap the image, create a DOM element "<IMG>" and set it's "SRC" attribute.  If you insert this image into your page, your browser will fetch it for you.   The fckeditor and other wysiwyg form editors are basically doing this for you today.

Comment: Yes, you can use the URL I mentioned in the first line of my answer as the src in an img. The browser will then display the image to the user, but javascript will have no access to the underlying image data.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of the file drag and drop using HTML5. This doesn't seem to work from one browser window to another(Desktop->browser works). But you can use this as a reference.

this is an experiment using web id to create a HTML5 form.

http://www.mattiasdanielsson.se/2010/building-innovative-login-html5-filereader/

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome you can use Copy/Paste, you'll need to copy the image by right-clicking and choosing "Copy Image", then you can paste it into another page that handles paste events with Ctrl+V.

Here is a demo illustrating the principle: http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/