# How to get URL of a dropped (linked) image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to retrieve a url of an image dropped into a div. This is the code I use:

```
$('#dropzone')
    .bind('dragenter dragover', false)
    .bind('drop', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
    });
```

Thing is, while it works great when dragging and dropping unlinked images (I get the `src` attribute of the `img` element), when I try to do this with images that they are links( `<a href="..."><img src="..."></a>`), I get the `href` attribute of the `a` element instead of the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Any ideas?

I don't care about browser compatibility, I want to make it work in Firefox (or Chrome) only.

**Edit: Here's how it looks like:** http://jsfiddle.net/SPdHR/2/

(seems to be working only in Firefox by the way)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19564982/746754.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#target')
    .bind( 'dragenter dragover', false)
    .bind( 'drop', function( e ) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var imageUrl = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    if($(imageUrl).children().length > 0 ){
        var url = $(imageUrl).find('img').attr('src');
    }else{        
        var url = $(imageUrl).attr('src');
    }
        $('#result').html(url);
    });
```

It works both on Firefox and Chrome(latest versions)
See updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SPdHR/39/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
$(e.target).find("img")
```

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest, I have no idea how to use it in this context. Could you take a look at the fiddle I just added? Thanks!

Comment: According to Chrome's console, `e.target` is the drag target, i.e. `<div id="target">DRAG A KITTEN HERE</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use after above code

```
 $('#dropzone')
.bind('dragenter dragover', false)
.bind('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
    var src = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var img = data.attr('src');   
    if (!img) {   
      var img = data.find("img").attr('src');

      alert(img);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to use a regular expression search of the dataTransfer text to find a string beginning with http:// and ending in " (but do not include the " in the result).

```
$('#dropzone')
.bind('dragenter dragover', false)
.bind('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.dataTransfer.files.length>0){
        //Handle the local file
    }
    else{
       //Find the url embedded in the dataTransfer data
        var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
        var matches = data.match(/http:\/\/.*(?=")/gi);
        var url = (matches || [false])[0]; //returns the url or false if no match found

        //Do whatever with the url
        console.log(url);
    }
});
```