# Implement drag and drop with different browser windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

How can I implement drag/drop functionality using two different browser windows?

I mean I want to enable the user to select an image from one browser window and drop the image in another browser window using javascript and jquery.

I just want the basic idea or algorithm for this.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think your scripts are limited to the current window, so you might not be able to access other *browser tabs* without a specific browser addon. - +1 for a really interesting question though. I wonder if I'm wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694631/html5-drag-and-drop-between-windows

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this probably to store the selected image information (filename) in a cookie so that is can be shared between browser tab/windows. When the user "drops" the image remove the cookie.

Comment: But how would I know that something is selected on some other window.
Actually the other window may be of some different website also.

Comment: You could implement some kind of *stash* in the window, you can drag your image into. Update your cookie, refresh the stash on the other page an drag it out of the *stash*. - With *stash* I mean a area (i.e. DIV) which could be a jQuery UI droppable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, at least cross-browser solution.

There are some technical demos where two windows interact with each other. One is called [Browser Ball](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/browser-ball/) for Chrome.

Maybe you could implement it differently.

If the user has **same** web site on both windows then you could implement similar thing like Chat window in the Google Mail <-> Google+. The same data appears on all windows and from the user perspective it's still the initial chat window.

User would drag & drop files to certain area on the page and it would appear in the other window. This requires either polling, [web sockets](http://websocket.org/quantum.html) or some other way to communicate with the server.