# C# Windows Application - Drag and Drop in web browser

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows

I am very new to microsoft technologies. my problem is-
I have a web browser control on a form. And i have a treeview control on the left side.
The treeview will consist of text node like 'Textbox', 'Radio', 'Select', 'Password'
etc and when the user will drag the node and drop to on the web browser control, then
there should be a textbox created on the web browser control. (if possible, on exact position where the user dropped the Node from TreeView control).

This may be a simple problem to you all. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: [HTML5 drag and drop between windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694631/html5-drag-and-drop-between-windows)

I explored this one as working example : [Drop image files here from your desktop](https://web.archive.org/web/20150623163248/http://studio.html5rocks.com:80/#Photos)

Ref:
[Cross Browser HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/)
[Drag and drop across browser windows?](https://ask.metafilter.com/48575/Drag-and-drop-across-browser-windows)

Hope this help to implement your functionality..