# Is it possible to drag and drop some content between two browser windows using JQuery or another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Basically, I have a popup window and I want ability to drag and drop an html item back to parent opener window. For example, if there is an image on the popup window which is draggable (and basically a handler only), once I drop it in the drop-zone of the parent window I just need to copy a hidden ID and/or maybe name of the Image from the popup to the parent window.

I can see plenty of examples on same page drag and drop but across windows? Is it possible? Both these windows have same website opened so I suppose there shouldn't be any cross-site issue thing?

Could you point me to the right direction? Anything not clear please ask.

**EDIT**

Is HTML5 an option?

**Another EDIT**

Is there another way to achieve above? i.e. different method than drag and drop - I am interested in transferring some data between one window to another here. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694631/html5-drag-and-drop-between-windows

Comment: I have already looked at that question and some others before posting mine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are after the HTML5 Drag and Drop API

A pretty good description: [DnD Basics](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

You can even drag and drop stuff between Firefox and Chrome. Safari is missing the drop event, should be out in the next release (6 if I'm right). Opera & IE is not supporting it yet.

Comment: the link unfortunately rotted. Here is an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20220615113502/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/