# $.getImageData not working because img-to-json is down?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, getimagedata

I'm trying to do some image processing on external images using [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/). I know that I need to use [$.getImageData](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/) to do operations on external images because otherwise you'll get DOM Exception 18 due to the canvas being "tainted by cross-origin data". Unfortunately, the appspot service "img-to-json" that $.getImageData uses is down with a "503 Over Quota" error, and has been for several days. I found another service called "img2json" that was actually working yesterday for a bit, but I'm not entirely sure it does the same thing (I think img2json only gives you the basic metadata as opposed to actual pixel data). So, my actual questions are:

- Are "img2json" and "img-to-json" the same service? If so, maybe I can just
  modify the $.getImageData code to use img2json.
- Is it common to see appspot applications being down like this? What
  are the chances of img-to-json coming back up in the recent future?
- If not, how easy would it be to temporarily download these external images to the server, do the image processing on them, then delete them? Is it possible to do that with only javascript?