# HTML5 drag and drop image between tabs IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I want to drag images from other websites into the dropzone on my website (between tabs/windows). This works with Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE 10 (same behaviour in gmail if you drop images into your email). In Firefox or Chrome the `evt.dataTransfer` contains enough information to either extract the URL or the image as a file.

```
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
... add more event listeners...

function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
    // in firefox this works:
    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));     ...
}
```

In IE10 the event doesn´t contain any useful information, it seems to get lost if I drag between tabs.

BUUUT, if i drop the image, IE navigates to the site where the image came from. Is there any way I can access this information? If I drop the image on my desktop I can dowload the picture.

How can I get the URL of the dropped image in IE 10?

Edit: there is a similar question here (didn´t help me) [HTML5 drag and drop between windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694631/html5-drag-and-drop-between-windows)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I also have a problem, but with IE 11. I have created a Javascript function which will help you a lot if you need to do this programmatically.