# Is there any way to drag a div to another window tab by jQuery or html5?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web application with bootstrap and i have many elements over there.

Actually i want to drag one element/Div to another browser's tab so is there any way to achieve this by jQuery or html?

The scene is my client has two screens and he wants to drag a map from web application to other screen but the rest of all elements/widget/divs will be still remain there.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: something similar was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694631/html5-drag-and-drop-between-windows)

Comment: Its not same, if we drop map over new tab, it loses all css and js of the page in new window.

Comment: even if you write the css inline in a `style="..."` attribute?